# Knockout : Changing input box value also change Root JSON corresponding value

Tags: knockout.js

Due to change in my root json im not able to reset my actual data.
Even in my subscribe function where i am getting oldvalue this value also updated with the changed input box

https://jsfiddle.net/asnastudio777/m4oh8x57/

```js
var jsonObj = {
    "value": "abc"
}
   function ViewModel (){
      this.someReview = ko.observable();
      this.prevValue =jsonObj;
   };
   var json = jsonObj;
   function ViewModelPrev (){
      this.someReviewPrev = ko.observable();
   };
   var vm = new ViewModelPrev();
   vm.someReviewPrev(json)
   ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel().someReview(jsonObj), document.getElementById('inputBox'));
   $('input').on('change', function(){
      
       $('#inputTest').text( 'Prev: ' + JSON.stringify(vm.someReviewPrev().value) + '\n' +
       'Current: ' + JSON.stringify(json))
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
   <p> Enter your reviews here: <br><br>
   <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: someReview().value" id="inputBox"/><br>
       
   </p>
   <div id="inputTest"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution:
we can make object immutable like converting object to stringify and then again parse it to JSON and then bind it on view

while binding
example:

```js
$.extend(clonedObj, MainObject);
myModelObject.modelProperty(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(clonedObj)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're storing a plain object inside an observable. Your `textInput` data-bind is bound to a *non-observable* property in this plain object. This means your input value is only set when you're applying bindings and there's no update or two-way value syncing.

The solution is to make the `value` property observable.

I've also included some "architectural" changes to show you how to debug/build without jQuery.

- A `ko.computed` is used to create a debug view of your viewmodel structure
- I've renamed your `objJSON` to `obj`, since it's not JSON.
- I've bound to the `body` element and used a `with` binding to target the input

```js
var obj = {
  "value": "abc"
}

function Review(data) {
  this.value = ko.observable(data.value);

  this.exportVM = ko.computed(function() {
    return {
      value: this.value()
    };
  }, this);
}

function App(reviewData) {
    this.someReview = new Review(reviewData);
    
    this.exportVM = ko.computed(function() {
      return {
        someReview: this.someReview.exportVM()
      };
    }, this);
    
 };
 
 ko.applyBindings(new App(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="with: someReview">
  <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: value"/>
</div>


<pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(exportVM(), null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answrer my question was i just dont want to update my json whenever i am changing my value from input

I cannot make my value property observable since i have created my entire div observable and then an elements inside are just bound with the json properties

Answer (score 1):

Try making a copy of the object and then use that copy to make edits
like
var newJob = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(job));

Answer (score 1):

As per your answer mentioned, the extend method performs the same task of making variable clonedObj immutable.
Also, you can stringify clonedObj at the time of declaration.